# Stuck dropdown box in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with many data validation by list drop down cells.
Every so often they get 'stuck' and the only solution is to delete the cell and recreate.
When stuck; drop down arrow is displayed without cell selected and when clicked displays blank list.

Seems that Excel draws a faint Drop Down shape when cell is selected; when this shape is clicked draws a solid Drop Down shape and the list.
When selection is made in the list, value goes in cell and Drop Down shape is deleted.
Only sometimes it isn't.

Is there a programmatic solution or is the only way really to manually fix any instance of 'stuck' drop down?

Comment: Even if your solution is programmatic, this is not a programming question. Perhaps you could edit it to fit the posting guidelines; I also don't see an actual question here.

Comment: This does sound like a SuperUser question but the answer below is fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have found is to select a cell without a drop down and delete all visible shapes with name 'Drop Down'. There may be invisible ones as well and deleting ANY of these will break ALL drop downs on the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Call KillStuckDropdown(Me.Name)
End Sub
```

And in module;

```
Sub KillStuckDropdown(wsName)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Shape

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheets(wsName)
ws.Range("AM1").Select
For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If InStr(1, sh.Name, "Drop") > 0 And sh.Visible Then
'            Debug.Print sh.Name
        sh.Delete
    End If
Next sh

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```